# Other profiles do not have access to RowCause field for sharing

Tags: sharing

I am sharing a record using a visualforce interface. When I log in as the System Admistrator and share the record it works fine but when I log in as a user from any other profile except Sys Admin it gives an error - **You do not have access to the following field: RowCause**

How do I give access to this field for other profiles?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a really weird answer...

First - check if you're really hitting the right error. Check http://www.tgerm.com/2012/01/field-is-not-writeable-sharerowcause.html for example - are you trying to re-share same record by any chance? They say they'll handle an update just fine but it worked for me only in batch job scheduled as sysadmin, not necessarily from code executed by end user.

---

Next - what's the row cause exactly you're trying to attack? Is it Account/Case/Opportunity (where you'd be better off utilising relevant `*TeamMember` object)? Or is it custom object?

I vaguely remember that for non-sysadmins & for custom objects the only available sharing reason is "Manual". Can't find the supporting piece of documentation, [this is sort-of related](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm#creating_apex_sharing).

---

Last resort - you might have to code something yourself that bypasses the field-level security.

I had similar problem with `AsyncApexJob` data (I wanted to expose the batch completion %, status, errors etc so my end users woul know if anything is running and wait before submitting new one). I ended up writing a simple wrapper class full of Strings, Integers and DateTimes and I was able to show this on VF page without any problems...

So try to describe the picklist manually, assign to a String merge field and give it a go?

Comment: I updated my question with the error message. The sharing is handled in a trigger so I modified the code to read the profile of the logged in user and then either provide RowCause with the sharing reason created by user (if profile is system admin) or Manual (if any other profile), but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: What if you'll leave it blank?

Comment: Isnt RowCause a required attribute when sharing?